# Is there an English equivalent to this French idiom : "Brasser du vent"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, pejorative-language, french

This idiom means "*Talking a lot without significant results*". I was wondering if there was a specific idiom to say this. So far, I have found nothing but "*hot air merchant*".

Comment: Please note: professional translators refer to equivalent ***meaning*** and not equivalent terms.

Comment: Also note that this question is asking for an *idiom* not a *word*.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate of these ***uncountably many*** entries in our `votable-thesaurus.stackexchange.com` game: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/453458
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/425013
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/383773
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/367828
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/342204
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/321485
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/316399
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/269467
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/250966

Comment: Still more related and possible duplicates from `votable-thesaurus.stackexchange.com`:
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/250348
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/242760
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/232063
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215722
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/203628
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/160126
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/107376
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96684
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/94774
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/59867
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/13277 ***The funnest game at SE!***

Comment: @tchrist Wow. That's a lot of dupes

Comment: Note that I'm not necessarily looking for an idiom, I mainly want to know if there is an equivalent and, if so, what is this said equivalent. I'm mainly interested in an equivalent for the first part of the definition because there are plenty of ways to express the second part.

Comment: @Hawker65 Did you go through all of tchrist's links? If you didn't find an answer there,can you explain how your question is different from all of those?

Comment: I did go through all of them and most of them were barely related to mine or were focussed on the second part of the definition which is more equivalent to "*Noyer le poisson*" than "*Brasser du vent*".

Answer (score 1):

[Hot air](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hot_air) is an expression that means

> Empty talk that is intended to impress.
>
> - ‘they dismissed the theory as a load of hot air’

We generally say someone is [*full* of hot air](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/full_of_hot_air)

> Talking a lot, especially without saying anything of value or meaning.
>
> - Did the salesman tell you anything new, or was he just full of hot air?

or that they are [blowing hot air](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/5694/Blow+hot+air)

> A person that has a lot of verbal wind that likes to sound off

Answer (score 1):

The single word ***bloviate***, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bloviate), means “to speak or write verbosely and windily”; [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bloviate) gives “Talk at length, especially in an inflated or empty way”.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloviation) suggests that the word is particularly associated with political speeches in Ohio, and U.S. President Warren G. Harding was particularly good at it.